# How to set the Chrome options same as the local browser to help capture the device id correctly?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing the fingerprinting capture software which amongst other attributes captures device_id.
Automate a scenario where we close one window and open another and verify the device ID on both the windows are the same.

More details: The scenario to test is
Test 1:

1. Initiate a web driver, open browser in local, navigate to a URL.
2. Open console and check the device_id captured by the software.
3. Call driver.close(); which will quit the driver.

Test 2:
4) Initiate second web driver, open browser in local, navigate to a URL.
5) Open console and check the device_id captured by the software.
6) Call driver.close(); which will quit the driver.

In the background, the fingerprinting capture software that I am testing captures the device_id. But in steps 2 and 5 I see the device id is different although I am running the test on my local.

When I do this manually, the device id is the same in both the tests.

I am thinking it could be the DesiredCapabilities which are different to the browser settings in local. How can I set the capabilities to mimic the local browser.

````
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/drivers/chromedriver_mac");
          
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("headless");
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", Boolean.valueOf(false));
            prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", Boolean.valueOf(false));
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

            // disable the AutomationControlled feature of Blink rendering engine
            options.addArguments("enable-automation", "false");
            options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");
            options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
            fdriver1 = new ChromeDriver(options);
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) fdriver1;
            js.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");


        }```
````